# Do Rakshasas have a gotra?

Tags: gotra, rakshasa

Did all Rakshasas descend only from Kashyapa or from other sages as well ?

Were Vasishta Agasthya of Rakshasa origin?

What proportion of Rakshasas were evil and what part pious and neutral judging from mythological descriptions ?

Comment: I have an interesting thing to comment. It might be wrong. At many places, I have seen Sanskrit word *Raksha* (or *Raksham*) being translated to *RAkshasa*. *Raksha* means "protection". Ok, other view: *Yaksha* is often an entity which usually protects or controls certain resource (e.g. cave, water, money etc.). Now typically *Yaksha* & *RAkshasa* are used in pair. So it's more likely that *RAkshasa* is not always some animalistic or creepy looking creature. Rather it's a protector entity. Often looking fearsome. In today's time, bodyguards or bouncers or rowdies are their equivalents.

Comment: Rakshasas and Yakshas are the two species which are **unrelated** to Kashyapa. Uttara Kanda of Ramayana relates that when Brahma was creating he created two sets of beings Rakshasas  (protectors) and Yakshas (horders). The leaders of these two species were also sons of Brahma namely Heti (Rakshasa) and Praheti (Yakshas).

Comment: Related: [Who are Yakshas?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8335/1049). Apparently, it seems that *Yaksha-RAkshasa* usually don't belong to *Brahmana gotra* due to predominant *Rajo guna* in them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rakshasas and Yakshas are perhaps the only two species **unrelated** to Maharshi Kashyapa. They are children of Lord Brahma. The creation of Rakshasas is described in the 4th chapter of the Uttara Kanda of Ramayana as well as in Puranas like Srimad Bhagavatam.

In the Uttara Kanda, Rishi Agastya tells Rama [the story of their creation](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/itihaas/ramayana/valmiki-ramayana-text-with-translation/vol-iv/chapter-04/topic-1), when Rama asked the same question as you.

Accordinglyy, Lord Brahma originally created denizens of water, who upon creation were very hungry and thirsty and asked Brahma what they must do.
Brahma asked them whether they will guard the waters. The beings who said, "Rakshaamah" or 'We will protect' became **Rakshasas** and those who said "Yakshaamah" or 'We will worship' became **Yakshas**.

Then Brahma created two more beings Heti and Praheti to be the leaders of the Rakshasas. Praheti proceeded to do Tapasya, while Heti married Bhaya, the sister of Lord Yama. They had a son called Vidyutkesha, whose son was Sukeshi.

Sukeshi had three sons, **Mali, Malyavan and Sumali**. Mali and Malyavan were killed by Vishnu during a war between Devas and Rakshasas. Sumali wanted revenge, and therefore asked his daughter **Kaikeshi** to marry sage **Vishrava**, the son of Pulastya, who was Kashyapa's uncle.

Vishrava already had a wife name Idavida, whose son Kubera became the King of Yakshas by worshipping Brahma. Kaikeshi married Vishrava and their children were **Ravana, Kumbhakarna, Vibheeshana and Surpanakha**.

When Ravana became King, since he was the grandson of Pulastya, it became common belief that like Kashyapa was the father of Devas, Pulastya was the father (or grandfather) of all Rakshasas, which was the confusion Rama had.

So to answer the question, Ravana and his family were of **Pulastya Gotra**, and the rest of the Rakshasas didn't have any Gotra, as they were directly descended from Brahma. (You can call them Brahma Gotra or Heti Gotra maybe...)

Comment: Nice answer, as finally someone describing *RAksha*s as not creepy creatures, but someone who is attached to protection. BTW, if you interested then you may also add a detail from Gita verse [17.4](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/17/4) that Yaksha-RAkshasa are usually *RAjasic* by nature. The people with predominant *Rajo guna* usually go in this category.

Comment: @Surya; What Gothra are Bali/Prahlad of?