# Are Yaksa, Raksasa, Pisacas demoniac forces that manifest according to 3 planes of existance?

Tags: puranas, asuras, classification, yakshas

I have been studying the differences of Yaksa, Raksasa, Pisacas. What I understand is there are 3 aspects of the demoniac force in nature. According to 3 planes of existence i.e., Bhuloka, Bhuvaloka, Suvaloka, demoniac energy manifest as these beings. Is there more to substantiate this idea?

Comment: Hinduism doesn't have concept of demoniac energy or any kind of ontological evil or source of evil etc. Yaksha, Rakshasa and Pishachas are ordinary souls like us, born in these particular yonis as per their past karmas and vasanas. There is nothing inherently evil about them. For all we know, any of us could have been one of them in past life.

Comment: Okay, but there is a classification difference between sura and asura. My understanding is that these beings belong to the asura category, by nature. Yes, the jivatma is born under those conditions, and you are correct that body is considered not independently, or ontologically evil, but rather I could have said three manifestations of a destructive or malefic type of shakti within the tamo-guna.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who are Yakshas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8335/who-are-yakshas)

Comment: What are 3 plane of existence?

Comment: Bhuh, Bhuvah, and Svah, or Bhuloka, Bhuvaloka, Suvaloka

Comment: So the Svar loka is a place for the Pisachas to live as per your understanding? Could not actually get what u meant.

Comment: What do you mean by according to 3 planes of existence? There are 14 planes of existence in Total (14 lokas).

Comment: No Pisachas move in the space between heaven and Earth, Raksasas move on Earth, Devas and Yakhsa move in heavenly realms (they can also visit Earth). The Puranas talk of 14 planes, yes but tri-lokya is a very common conception, and term used in the Vedas. So its not so cut and dry. 

1) bhuloka: "Earth world," the physical plane. 2) antarloka: "Inner or in-between world," the subtle or astral plane. 3) Sivaloka: "World of Siva," 
http://veda.wikidot.com/triloka

Comment: "The most common cosmological conception of lokas in the Veda was that of the trailokya or triple world: three worlds consisting of earth, atmosphere or sky, and heaven, making up the universe."[3]"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loka

So, 14 planes is a more detailed description of the trailokya "triple world" cosmological system. This fits with the three main Urthva Lokas, as well [Bhur, Bhuva, Swarga]. These beings seem to logically fit into these categories, and I have read this correlation before, but wanted to substantiate it.

Comment: The Yaksas are living in outer to Kailash near Shiva, with Kubera who is a Yaksa, so the original question is not that illogical, but maybe I could have have worded it better.

Comment: if you are searching for something deeply evil(as of now) in hinduism, then that is "kali the demon of kaliyuga"