# What are Yakshas and Yakshinis? Are they spiritually advanced astral beings? Are they powerful than humans?

Tags: karma, yakshas

I read over internet that Yakshas and Yakshinis if worshipped can bestow almost all material comforts upon you. 
Is it true?
What made them so powerful? 
Were they spiritual in their Human lives? What kind of karma makes a person Yaksha after death?

Comment: There are methods given in the Tantras to appease the Yakshinis. So I can partially answer this one.

Comment: Related and already asked who are Yakshas [Who are Yakshas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8335/5212). As of now, it's a partial duplicate.