# Why scriptures show demons(Rakshasa) as evil while they protect people?

Tags: ramayana, rakshasa

Whenever we read our scriptures, we see the demons(Rakshasa) as people having evil powers and they always busy in troubling others. But I was stunned when I read the etymology of Rakshasa in Ramayana.

- Valmiki Ramayana 7:4:12-13[image]

> If asuras are the protector, why scriptures show thenlm as evil?

Comment: Every rakshasa is not bad (Prahlada, Bali etc.) and every rakshasa is not good (tadkasura, Hiranya Kashyapa etc.)

Comment: @Vishvam, exceptions don't define the rule. Majority of asuras are evil. Majority of devas are good. We should not make it seem like they're 50-50. That would be like saying 'not all 10th dropouts fail in life', while referring to Sachin Tendulkar, who is a rare exception. Vast majority of 10th dropouts don't do well in life. Advice must be catered for the majority. The exceptions will shine despite the discouraging advice.

Comment: @ram May be word "rakshasa" meant something else earlier than what we know today. If we go for demons/devil then most of them are bad as we heard/read in history.

Comment: @Vishvam Prahlad, Bali are not Rakshasa, they are Daityas...

Comment: @SanatanDarshan they don't protect people, they protect water... u can find ur answer in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22925/12304 post ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who are Yakshas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8335/who-are-yakshas)