# Why was Bali Raja considered a demon?

Tags: asuras, bali

Why was Bali Raja considered a demon? Please explain in detail and provide a link to the scriptural reference if any.

Comment: Bali raja was born in the Daitya lineage, his great grand father being Hiranyakashipu, son of Diti and Kashyap. Hence Bali raja is a Daitya.

Comment: I do not think Bali is a demon. Bali was an asura based on his lineage. I think equating asuras to demons is a fallacy.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the races are named after wives of Kaśyapa. For example,

- Descendants of Aditi: Adityas (Devas)
- Descendants of Danu: Danavas
- **Descendants of Diti: Daityas**

Origin of Rakshasas is different which is described [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8335/who-are-yakshas/22925#22925).

Though Danavas, Daityas and Rakshasas are used interchangeably or collectively (as demon or asura) but they are different.

---

As per [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) » Skandha 6: CHAPTER EIGHTEEN](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/6/18/), Bali Mahārāja was born in Diti's line:

> Diti > Hiraṇyakaśipu > Prahlāda > Virocana > Bali Mahārāja

That's why he is referred as Daitya.

Comment: Nice answer YDS!