# How did Ravana got soldiers to defeat Kubera to win Lanka?

Tags: ramayana, ravana

How did Ravana got soldiers to defeat Kubera to win Lanka?

Ravana was born in Brahmin orthodox family and he was born and brought up in Brahmins Kutira. So, how he got/gathered soldiers to defeat Kubera to win Lanka.

Did his grand father helped by giving his soldiers?

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Defeating Kubera was easier because they are relatives. Kubera is not going to kill his brother even over something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ravana's maternal grandfather Sumali and maternal uncles were Rakshasas and they encouraged Ravana to take back Lanka from Kubera as Rakshasas used to rule it earlier.

Kubera consulted his father Visrava when Ravana sent Prahasta to Kubera as messenger and as per his father's advice Kubera with his followers shifted to mount Kailasha leaving Lanka for Ravana.

So, Ravana had Rakshasas' army but he got Lanka without any war. Though, later on he attacked Kubera and Yakshas in mount Kailasha after becoming Lanka and Rakshasas' ruler.

References: [VALMIKI RAMAYANA: UTTARA KANDA: SECTION 11](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-11)

---

Related: [How were Rakshas created?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48243/how-were-rakshas-created/48244#48244)